# Ambiguous operator<< selection

Tags: c++11, sfinae, overload-resolution, ambiguous-call

I have some code which, very much simplified, looks somewhat like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace X {
    struct Foo {int x;};
    struct Bar {int x;};

    template <typename T , typename = typename std::enable_if<
                                                              std::is_same<decltype(T::x),int>::value
                                                             >::type>
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const T&) {
        return os;
    }
}

namespace Y {
    struct Faa : X::Foo {int y;};
    struct Baz {int x; int y;};

    template <typename T , typename = typename std::enable_if<
                                                              std::is_same<decltype(T::x),int>::value && 
                                                              std::is_same<decltype(T::y),int>::value
                                                             >::type>
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const T&) {
        return os;
    }
}


int main() {
    // Everything is ok
    X::Foo x;
    std::cout << x;

    Y::Baz k;
    std::cout << k;

    // Problems..
    Y::Faa y;

    // std::cout << y; // <--operator is ambiguous
    Y::operator<<(std::cout, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the ambiguous operator for `Y::Faa` and having to manually specify `Y::operator<<`? If not, why?

Comment: The restriction imposed via `enable_if` seems quite weak (too many types are allowed). Can you refine them e.g. by using a type trait?

Comment: In my actual code I have made an actual trait which checks the existence of various member methods, but the idea is the same. I don't think this is yet a problem here though.

Comment: I rather thought of something like a list of allowed types; something that lets you "determine" which types are (intended as) direct members of a namespace. From those, you can then select those with a member named `x`.

Comment: @dyp The problem is that these functions are part of a library and the user may want to call them with custom types.

Answer (score 3):

Two functions have a conflict because conditions on their arguments have non-empty intersection (actually, 1st supersedes 2nd). Function overloading works only if signatures are different. So, to solve this we have 2 options:

**Change conditions** so that they have empty intersection (manually forbid having `y` field by adding `&& !sfinae_has_member_y<T>::value` condition to the 1st `enable_if`)

```
template<typename T>
struct sfinae_has_member_y {
    static int has(...);
    template<typename U = T, typename = decltype(U::y)>
    static char has(const U& value);
    enum { value = sizeof(char) == sizeof(has(std::declval<T>())) };
};
```

OR use another C++ feature that supports arguments overlapping, like **struct/class template specialization**. If you replace `bool` with `int`, other fields may be added too:

```
template<typename T, bool>
struct Outputter {
};
template<typename T>
struct Outputter<T, false> {
    static std::ostream & output(std::ostream & os, const T&) {
        os << "x";
        return os;
    }
};
template<typename T>
struct Outputter<T, true> {
    static std::ostream & output(std::ostream & os, const T&) {
        os << "y";
        return os;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(T::x), int>::value>>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const T& a) {
    return Outputter<T, sfinae_has_member_y<T>::value>::output(os, a);
}
```